# Comparing the Performance of Pointers' Allocation in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, pointers, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

What is the best way to compare pointers allocation/de-allocation in C/C++? Please consider the performance as the point of view.

The code includes a comparison of the following dynamic allocation types:

- `Malloc/Free`
- `New/Delete`
- `std::auto_ptr`
- `std::shared_ptr`
- `std::unique_ptr`
- `std::allocator/deallocator`

Let's start with this code snippet:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // I intended to use C for malloc. Though not cstdlib
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

#define Million 1000000
#define Alls 100 * Million

long calculate_time(struct timeval start, struct timeval end){

    long start_micro = (start.tv_sec * Million) + start.tv_usec;
    long end_micro = (end.tv_sec * Million) + end.tv_usec;
    long elapsed_time = end_micro - start_micro;
    std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << elapsed_time << " usec";
    std::cout << " (" << Alls / elapsed_time << " allocations/microseconds)" << std::endl;
}


/* 
* Version: C
* Allocation: Malloc
* Deallocation: Free
*/
void c_pointer (){


    int counter = 0;
    do{

        int *p = (int *) malloc (sizeof (int));
        *p =5;
        free(p);
        counter ++;
    } while (counter < Alls);
}


/* 
* Version: C++98
* Allocation: New
* Deallocation: Delete
*/
void cpp98_pointer (){

    int counter = 0;
    do{

        int *p = new int (5);
        delete p;
        counter ++;
    } while (counter < Alls);
}


/* 
* Version: C++98 till C++17
* Allocation: std::auto_ptr
* Deallocation: Automatically
*/
void cpp98_auto_ptr (){

    int counter = 0;
    do{
        std::auto_ptr<int> p(new int);
        *p = 5;
        counter ++;
    } while (counter < Alls);
}


/* 
* Version: C++11
* Allocation: std::shared_ptr
* Deallocation: Automatically
*/
void cpp11_shared_ptr (){

    int counter = 0;
    do{
        std::shared_ptr<int> p(new int);
        *p = 5;
        counter ++;
    } while (counter < Alls);
}


/* 
* Version: C++11
* Allocation: std::unique_ptr
* Deallocation: Automatically
*/
void cpp11_unique_ptr (){

    int counter = 0;
    do{
        std::unique_ptr<int> p(new int); 
        *p = 5;
        counter ++;
    } while (counter < Alls);

}


/* 
* Version: C++98
* Allocation: std::allocator
* Deallocation: Deallocate
*/
void cpp98_allocator (){

    int counter = 0;
    do{

        std::allocator<int> a;
        int* p = a.allocate(1);
        a.construct(p, 1);
        *p =5;
        a.deallocate(p, 1);
        counter ++;
    } while (counter < Alls);

}


int main (){

    for (int i= 0 ; i < 6; i++){

        struct timeval t1, t2;
        gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);

        switch(i){
            case 0:
                std::cout << "C - Malloc/Free:" << std::endl;
                c_pointer();
                break;
            case 1:
                std::cout << "C++98 - New/Delete:" << std::endl;
                cpp98_pointer();
                break;
            case 2:
                // From C++98 until C++17 (Removed in C++17)
                std::cout << "C++98 - auto_ptr:" << std::endl;
                cpp98_auto_ptr();
                break;
            case 3:
                // From C++11
                std::cout << "C++11 - shared_ptr:" << std::endl;
                cpp11_shared_ptr();
                break;
            case 4:
                // From C++11
                std::cout << "C++11 - unique_ptr:" << std::endl;
                cpp11_unique_ptr();
                break;
            default:
                // Deprecated in C++98
                std::cout << "C++98 - Default Allocator:" << std::endl;
                cpp98_allocator();
                break;
        }

        gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
        calculate_time(t1, t2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

On my own laptop, results are as follows:

```
C - Malloc/Free:
Elapsed time: 1519052 usec (65 allocations/microseconds)
C++98 - New/Delete:
Elapsed time: 1718064 usec (58 allocations/microseconds)
C++98 - auto_ptr:
Elapsed time: 2334505 usec (42 allocations/microseconds)
C++11 - shared_ptr:
Elapsed time: 10197285 usec (9 allocations/microseconds)
C++11 - unique_ptr:
Elapsed time: 11785931 usec (8 allocations/microseconds)
C++98 - Default Allocator:
Elapsed time: 3487610 usec (28 allocations/microseconds)
```

Comment: Strike `std::auto_ptr` and `malloc`/`free` from your list. Don't use those in modern C++.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, you are right. This is why I mentioned that std::auto_ptr is removed in C++17. As for malloc/free, it is coupled with C language as we are unable to use other pointers in C.

Comment: Are stats on the allocation/release of one int useful??

Comment: You have answered your question. What exactly do you need to know ? Though one suggestion is to alloc/dealloc bigger sizes instead of an int. It may show a different statistic.

Comment: @Mazhar, Indeed I just want some comments about it. Probably, someone would provide some optimized way.

Comment: @MartinJames, this is the first time I use allocation/release. So, I did not get your point.

Comment: Are you compiling your test with optimizations enabled? If not, do so. Benchmarking unoptimized debug builds is pointless.

Comment: A benchmark program without compiler settings is not admissible in the court of law.

Comment: As a nitpick, `std::allocator` and `std::auto_ptr` are both from C++98.

Comment: In performance sensitive code paths you don't want to allocate at all.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I intended to neglect optimizations to have a fair comparison. I am afraid that an optimization would affect one pointer more than other!! Do you have some recommendations?

Comment: @CandyGumdrop You are Right!!

Comment: Recommendation: test the things you want to compare, which is very likely not single `int` allocations without any optimisation. You have meaningless numbers here

Comment: @Mohamad-JaafarNEHME You would never ship an unoptimized build to customers, so optimized performance is what matters. Additionally, in unoptimized/debug builds your standard library usually ads a *ton* of code that makes checking validity easier but also slows things down *enormously* - you don't want to benchmark that. Also, a lot of abstractions (like `std::unique_ptr`) are explicitly *designed* to optimize away completely, so they only have a real cost in unoptimized builds. Performance of debug builds is irrelevant, they are artificially slow and don't reflect real world performance.

Comment: Also you've got the units wrong on you report, it's allocations per **microsecond**, which is still inordinately slow

Comment: @Mohamad-JaafarNEHME Also, what is slowest in a debug build can *easily* be the fastest once you enable the optimizer. So, if you pick your solution based on numbers from debug builds you may very well be picking a sub-optimal solution.

Comment: I've voted to close this question as another call for cargo cult c++ programming optimization.

Comment: @Caleth thank you. I corrected it.

Comment: This is completely meaningless. For example the function `c_pointer` does not have *any* side effects at all, hence it is functionally equivalent to `void c_pointer () { }` and will be replaced by such by an optimizing compiler.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, if the compiler is going to optimize the c_pointer functionality and remove its content, why did we get around one and half seconds to compute it?! Empty loop of 10millions consumes less than milliseconds!!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Would you please demonstrate that?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/Ozexk1

Comment: @AnttiHaapala you are right. You could notice that all the comments are talking about the optimization. Even though I know that an optimizing compiler would neglect my functions' content, I intended to neglect optimizations during the compilation. This is to perform tests and fair comparison only. Makes sense?

Answer (score -2):

First, when you compile with retail optimizations turned on, you get dramatically different results.   (My quick port to Windows and some fixups in your code, including not taking a timing measurement until after the cout statement):

```
C - Malloc/Free:
Elapsed time: 469 msec     (21321 allocations/second)
C++98 - New/Delete:
Elapsed time: 500 msec     (20000 allocations/second)
C++11 - auto_ptr:
Elapsed time: 484 msec     (20661 allocations/second)
C++11 - shared_ptr:
Elapsed time: 1157 msec     (8643 allocations/second)
C++11 - unique_ptr:
Elapsed time: 484 msec     (20661 allocations/second)
```

Everything but the shared_ptr has the same speed.   `shared_ptr` has to allocate some locking constructs (mutex) since it has be thread safe with regards to reference countnig and weak_ptr assignments.

Second, your methodology is flawed, each allocation is followed by a deallocation followed by an identically sized allocation.  It's possible the compiler can just optimize that all away since the allocation pointer is not used for anything.

And it's also likely that the top level memory manager can give return a pointer fast from the heap since it has just been handed back a pointer of identical size.  It never has to go back to the lower heap to increase the heap.

Comment: "retail optimizations" ?  Don't you mean "*release* optimizations"? I think you are confused about what "retail" means.

Comment: "Elapsed time: 469 msec     (21321 allocations/second)" - the math doesn't work.... ~500ms would be ~2 allocations per second. Which is obviously wrong.

Comment: "including not taking a timing measurement until after the cout statement" - Why would you want to time `cout` in a benchmark of allocations?

Comment: @JesperJuhl - You misread.  The Op's code was include the cout statement in the print statement. I moved that out in my local compile such that the print statement wasn't impacting the measure run time.  Make sense?